# Why is Chrome giving me a width of 0 for this table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I figured I would ask this question just to see if anyone knows why this happened - even though I'm fairly certain it is a bug with Chrome.

The version of Chrome I am using is : Version 30.0.1599.69 m (the latest version at the time of this post)

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4Q5/

HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="testWidth">
            This should have some width
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#myTable {
  background-color:#4679bd
}
#testWidth {
 padding: 0;
 width: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
var width = document.getElementById('testWidth').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = width + 'px';
```

The page will show a blue box that contains some text. This blue box obviously has some width to it - since it takes up space. But the CSS has specified a width of 0, which actually should just be a suggestion, whereas the table cell will actually get its width from some child that has pushed it around.

Somehow javascript is saying that the offsetWidth of the table-cell is 0.

All other browsers will give the actual offset width of this table-cell as some non-zero value. Including if you test on Chrome v29 or lower.

Only Chrome v30 seems to have this issue.

Anyone know what is going on here? Or should I just sit around waiting for Chrome developers to fix the bug?

Perhaps I am relying on the offsetWidth when I should not be relying on this?

This seems like a clear violation of W3C specs - maybe I am wrong?

Also - it seems as though Chrome is not wrapping the text at all - but all other browsers will wrap the text because I have specified a width of 0 in CSS it should try to minimize the width wherever possible.

Please note - if you change the width of the #testWidth cell, the offset will just change to have that width - i.e. you could say 10px instead of 0, and the output will be 10. So the offsetWidth is just taking whatever width I put in CSS, which is wrong... right??

Comment: Tried on Chrome 29 and 32, and both seem to be ok.

Comment: It looks to be a bug with Chrome 30. You should report this to them, or at least check to make sure they know about it.

Comment: Tested on Chrome 31beta, problem exists. But `clientWidth` is OK.

Comment: Tried on 30 and it is not working, clientWidth is fine as Korpela said

Comment: I have reported a bug with Chrome using the "report an issue" button under tools. @NuclearGhost when you say "both seem ok" you mean that the width is given as some non-zero value?

Comment: @codefactor yes both report non-zero `offsetWidth`

Comment: @NuclearGhost Thank you, that hopefully means that Google Chrome has already fixed in v32, but I wonder when my Chrome version will auto-update to v32.

Comment: jQuery outerWidth seems to report the correct number: var width = $('#testWidth').outerWidth();, I know it is not exactly the same as offsetWidth, but in this case it probably gives you what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this bug by removing the `width: 0;` from your css, you can also change it to either max- or min-width.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4Q5/4/

Comment: I need the width 0 for my case in order to make the width of the column as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width for that id in the CSS. Remove `width: 0;` in your CSS.

Your CSS should then look like this and your problem will go away.

```
#myTable {
  background-color:#4679bd
}
#testWidth {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That is the whole point - it is ok to set a width of a column in CSS for a table cell - but the offsetWidth of that table cell should not be the width of the cell, but instead the actual width. In my case the `width:0` is used to make sure that the column is as small as possible - it is a mere "suggestion" to the layout engine for the width of that column.

Comment: By the way - after the comments to my original post, I believe the answer to my question is that it is a bug in Chrome v30